# case when returning duplicates

Tags: sql, case

thanks for helping in advance

I have a table named houses with houses informations
and I have a table, periods which contains the periods in which the houses are available
[periods table with the start and the end of the period][1]

I have to check if the house is available yes our no on the period in between '2022-12-19' AND '2023-01-02'(included)

this is my code and it returns duplicates sometimes, in that case the one is **true** the other is **false**

And I want to display **true** whenever the house has at least one period that is between '2022-12-19' AND '2023-01-02'(included)

- This is the result

````
CASE
WHEN (periods.start_at BETWEEN '2022-12-18' AND '2023-01-03') AND (periods.end_at BETWEEN '2022-12-21' AND '2023-01-03')
THEN TRUE 
ELSE FALSE
END AS vancances_noel,


FROM houses
LEFT JOIN destinations on houses.destination_id=destinations.id
LEFT JOIN periods on houses.id=periods.house_id```
````

Comment: Please proofread your question and add proper sample data and expected results as text, not as [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please tag the request with the DBMS you are using in order to get answers that work for you. It can make a big difference if you use MySQL or SQL Server or PostgreSQL or ...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this:

CASE WHEN (cast(periods.start_at as date) BETWEEN '2022/12/18' AND '2023/01/03') AND (cast(periods.end_at as date) BETWEEN '2022/12/21' AND '2023/01/03')

There may be some confusion as to whether periods.start_at or periods.end_at are date values or whether the strings used in the BETWEEN operator are date values.

Answer (score 0):

sql query will display n times ( n nomber periods) and each line has status of period , so to show which avaible only
your sql should be:

```
    select houses.id, periods.start_at,periods.end_at FROM houses
LEFT JOIN destinations on houses.destination_id=destinations.id
LEFT JOIN periods on houses.id=periods.house_id
where (periods.start_at BETWEEN '2022-12-18' AND '2023-01-03') AND (periods.end_at BETWEEN '2022-12-21' AND '2023-01-03')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your period match looks wrong. Isn't a house also available from December 18 to January 3, when there is, say, an available period from December 15 to January 10?

Then, for your lookup, don't join but use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT
  some_columns,
  EXISTS
  (
    SELECT NULL
    FROM periods p
    WHERE periods.house_id = h.id
    AND start_at <= DATE '2022-12-18'
    AND end_at >= DATE '2023-01-03'
  ) AS vancances_noel,
  more_columns
FROM houses h
LEFT JOIN destinations d ON h.destination_id = d.id
```